# How can I send audio from a Linux box to a Mac?

Tags: networking, audio, home-networking, media-center, audio-streaming

I have a Mac mini connected to my TV and sound system. I would like to use it as an audio 'server' in the sense that it will receive network audio and play it to the speakers.

My client is a Linux laptop running Ubuntu.

Solutions like [Airfoil](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/) don't seem to handle this setup (Airfoil has only linux 'speakers' software, no client).

Any ideas on a quick setup to enable this? There's no need for multichannel or other fanciness, just audio redirecting. I've looked at [Jack](http://jackaudio.org/) and [Jack OS X](http://jackosx.com/), but they seem like overkill and I haven't figured out how to configure them.

Comment: Did you try with VLC? It can act as server/client for audio streaming.

Comment: This will sound really lofty but, you've reversed the server / client model, The server would be the Linux box and the Mac Mini would be the client #condescending